# Reading input from a text file, converting into int, and storing into array.

Tags: c#

I need some help. I have a text file that looks like so:

21,M,S,1
22,F,M,2
19,F,S,3
65,F,M,4
66,M,M,4

What I need to do is put the first column into an array int[] age and the last column into an array int[] districts. This is for a college project due in a week. I've been having a lot of trouble trying to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I did try searching for an answer already but didn't find anything that i understood. I also cannot use anything we havent learned from the book, so it rules out lists<> and things of the like.

```
FileStream census = new FileStream("census.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); 
        StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader(census);
        string input = "";

        string[] fields;
        int[] districts = new int[SIZE];
        int[] ageGroups = new int[SIZE];

        input = inFile.ReadLine();

        while (input != null)
        {
            fields = input.Split(',');


            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                int x = int.Parse(fields[i]);

                districts[i] = x;

            }
            input = inFile.ReadLine();


        }
        Console.WriteLine(districts[0]);
```

Comment: @MethodMan Did you read the question carefully? He already said this is homework and thus limited to methods taught in class, and specifically mentioned `List<>` being out. Additionally, he definitely needs to split multiple times in the loop because he is reading by line.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that `SIZE` will always be equal to or larger than the number of lines in the input? If so, then I think that the answer that "Russ" is working on (he's hiding it as a deleted answer, but it'll probably show up soon) should work. If not, please clarify your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. State clearly what the exact requirements are, and what specifically isn't working for you (besides the part that Russ has already addressed).

Comment: @Setsu sorry about that I did not see that homework part.. well there is always a way to skin this cat the old fashion way..

Comment: By the way, both `FileStream` and `StreamReader` implement the `IDisposable` interface, so you should wrap them in `using` statements. [Here's](http://www.dotnetperls.com/using) a great place to start learning about them, as well as other C# related stuff.

Comment: @PeterDuniho For my example, yes, SIZE is set to 50. However, after reading your question I went back and looked at my professors email, and it states that the program must work given any size list. I apologize, I will read through the how-to-ask link you mentioned and ask a more clearly stated question with my specific requirements.

Answer (score 3):

if your file is nothing but this then `File.ReadAllLines()` will return a string array with each element being a line of your file. Having done that, you can then use the length of the returned array to initialize the other two arrays, into which the data will be stored.

Once you have your string array you call `string.Split()` on each element with "," as your delimiter, now you will have another array of strings minus the commas, you will them take the values you want by their index position, 0 and 3 respectively, and you can store those somewhere. Your code would look something like this:

```
//you will need to replace path with the actual path to the file.
string[] file = File.ReadAllLines("path");
int[] age = new int[file.Length];
int[] districts = new int[file.Length];
int counter = 0;

foreach (var item in file)
{
    string[] values = item.Split(',');
    age[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
    districts[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(values[3]);
    counter++
}
```

Comment: As mentioned above he can not use lists.

Comment: Also, he's a student trying to learn the language. Spoon-feeding him the code isn't going to help him much.

Comment: it might not help him, but it might help someone else who reads this post. Also I missed the part about no lists, Made the changes necessary.

Comment: @Setsu: there is of course a lot of debate around the question of answering homework questions. However, IMHO there is nothing at all wrong with providing code, provided such code comes with a detailed explanation of how and why the code works/solves the problem. Frankly, this answer came the closest to providing good, specific advice; I've edited to clean it up a bit and add to the detail that makes it a good answer for _homework_.

Comment: Thank you, im new to the stackoverflow community and I will remember to include detailed explanation of the how and why going forward.

Comment: This worked perfectly. But rather than just using the code I would like to learn from it. So my first question would be, i've never seen the File.ReadAllLines("path"); before, although I don't think my professor will have a problem with it. Does it essentially work the same way I used? And then store each line in an array index?

Comment: Yes, it stores each line into an array of strings, with the first line being in the 0 index position. It has the added benefit of not needing to close a file stream as it self-closes. with each line being a string in an array, you then need to parse each of those strings(lines of your file), that is where the foreach loop comes in, it splits up your line into a separate string array delimited by "," the 0 and 3 index being your numbers, those numbers are then stored into the age and district int arrays, and the counter is there to make sure that they are stored in the correct index position

Comment: @MichaelSnapp: note that if your professor tells you that you aren't allowed to use `File.ReadAllLines()`, another alternative is to just read through the file once without doing anything except counting lines. Then you can use that count for the rest of the algorithm, reading the file again to actually process the text.

Comment: Thank you both very much for your help in this matter! My class is pretty challenging only because my professor only teach's "the basics of programming" and hardly goes into syntax because he says "This is not a language class" which makes things challenging. In psuedocode, it's easy as pie, but learning the syntax requires me to look almost everything up. Again, thank you so very much for your help, I actually learned because I will not simply just copy and paste!

Answer (score 2):

Proper way of *writing* this code:

Write each step your trying to perform:

```
// open file
// for each line 
//     parse line
```

Then refine "parse line"

```
// split by fields
// parse and handle age
// parse and handle gender
// parse and handle martial status
// parse and handle ....
```

Then start writing missing code.

At that point you should figure out that iterating through fields of single record not going to do you any good as all fields have different meaning.

So you'll need to remove `for` and replace it with filed-by-field parsing/assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through all your fields, simply refer to the actual index of the field:

Wrong:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    int x = int.Parse(fields[i]);
    districts[i] = x;
}
```

Right:

```
districts[i] = int.Parse(fields[0]);
ageGroups[i] = int.Parse(fields[3]);
i++;
```

Comment: I apologize, but It wasn't until re-reading my professors email that this program must work regardless of length. I see why the for loop doesn't work now. Thank you for this. How would you go about making this program work regardless of length. Would it be to put the entire txt file into a string and call the .length function?

Answer (score 0):

So I just made some BS to do what you are seeking.  I do not agree with it because I hate directly hardcoding for split, but since you can't use a list this is what you get:

```
FileStream census = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader(census);

int[] districts = new int[1024];
int[] ageGroups = new int[1024];
int counter = 0;

string line;
while ((line = inFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
     string[] splitString = line.Split(',');
     int.TryParse(splitString[0], out ageGroups[counter]);
     int.TryParse(splitString[3], out districts[counter]);
     counter++;          
}
```

This will give you two arrays, `districts` and `ageGroups` that are of length `1024` and will contain the values for each row in the census.txt file.

Comment: This will fail for inputs > 1024 lines.

Comment: @PeterDuniho This is why I made sure to note that it is for only 1024 inputs.

Comment: From the OP's comment: _"the program must work given any size list"_